# How do I specify an object in ASP.NET Web API route decorations?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I can understand this:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(OrderModel))]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrderById(int customerId, int orderId)
```

But how can I set the route decoration for the following three methods:

```
// GET: api/Content
public IQueryable<Content> Get()
{
    return db.Contents;
}

// GET: api/Content/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Content))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    Content content = await db.Contents.FindAsync(id);
    if (content == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(content);
}

// PUT: api/Content/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, Content content)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

I cannot find any examples of where there are no input parameters or where input parameters contain objects to be JSON serialized like in this example which was working well before I tried to user Route Decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but [this](http://attributerouting.net/#route-prefixes) attribute routing explanation might help.